# My avatar command isn't working - How do I fix it?

Tags: python, discord, avatar

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member=None):
        if not member:
            member = ctx.message.author
        favatar = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s avatar", color=0x000000)
        favatar.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}")

        favatar.set_image(url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url))
        await ctx.send(embed = favatar)
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

It gives me an error:

> Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no
> attribute 'message'

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    favatar = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s avatar", color=0x000000)
    favatar.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}")
    favatar.set_image(url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url))

    await ctx.send(embed = favatar)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: @ChaosVoxXD please click the accept button below the downvote button next to my answer if this helped you out!